# How to access numeric data from API call?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am accessing data on futures prices from the Chicago Mercantile Exchange via API calls.

I am using an URL which, when I post it in a browser, returns a csv-file (gzip compressed). I do however need to write a program in python that can take in several thousand URLs and handle the data it receives. When using this URL in a requests.get() command in python, I get a response which I do not know how to read.

```
import requests

url='https://datamine.cmegroup.com/cme/api/v1/download?fid=20181211- 
EOD_xcbt_ff_fut_0-eth_p'
user = '***'
password = '***'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
print(r.headers)
```

Which, among other things, returns:

```
{
    'Date': 'Sun, 30 Dec 2018 13:01:07 GMT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip',
    'Content-Length': '1287',
    'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="xcbt-eodp-ff-fut-20181211.csv.gz"'
}
```

I assume that the prices I am trying to obtain are contained in the element `'attachment; filename="xcbt-eodp-ff-fut-20181211.csv.gz"'`.

**My question:**

How do I obtain the prices from the response I am getting?
Then, how do I import the data into a `DataFrame`?

Simply using:

```
print(r.content)
```

does not return numeric values.

Comment: Please, take a look on the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). You will need to use either `r.text` or `r.json()`.

Comment: Looks like the API isn't returning the exact data, but instead the filename of a gziped CSV.  You'd need to first [download this](https://www.codementor.io/aviaryan/downloading-files-from-urls-in-python-77q3bs0un), uncompress the file, then load the CSV into python in such a manner that you can then read the individual fields.  Depedning on the volume of data you may wish to have a frist script which handles queriying the API and downloading the `csv.gz` files to uncompress them, then a second script which reads in the CSV files (from local disk)  and does further analysis on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
resp = requests.get(url)

# for now it's a Response object. Make a json out of it
json_resp = resp.json()

print(json_resp.get('some_key')) # or what ever you need
```

Then use a simple dict functionality to extract what ever you need..